# Swift - cornerRadius on Image doesn't work

Tags: swift, image, uiimageview, cornerradius

In my tableviews custom cell I have an image:

[image: Image of my tableview]

I want to get the cornerRadius = 20.
But for some reason it won't work I have used this code:

```
cell.offerImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20
cell.offerImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

And the Imageviews content mode is Aspect Fit. It is funny, because I tried to play around with it, and when I used:

```
cell.offerImage.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.offerImage.frame.size.width / 2
```

I got some weird cornerRadius, not the round as I expected. It is like the cornerRadius is on the imageView and not the image, and I dont know the precise size of the image (uploaded from server).

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me
I am have checked **clipsToBound** in the **.xib** file

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```